# Assigning values on multiple clients in UE4

Tags: c++, multiplayer, unreal-4, blueprints

I am currently working on a multiplayer game and I am having difficulties on assigning values on variables for each clients. Originally I looped through available clients character from HUD then assigned the calculated the value but I decided to do it inside character blueprint's instead.

I don't know why only first clients gets the calculated values but the other client still having the default value.

This is the initial value that I assigned from inside Character C++

```
MaxHealth = 500;
Health = MaxHealth;
```

This is how I assigned the value from the Blueprint.
[image]

Set Initial Attributes is where I calculated the Health value based on player's Strength value etc and the reason I'm doing this is because I am planning to retrieve the stats from the datatable in the future. But I don't know why it becomes like this instead.

This is the correct final value that supposedly assigned on both clients.
[image: First Client]

But only first client gets the correct value, not second client.
[image: Second Client]

I don't want to use loop to search the player characters' inside player character's blueprint and assigned the value because I don't think it's a wise move so I am looking for a better alternative if any. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up calculate all the values inside the C++ instead and I'm not sure why I can't do it in the blueprints. From the log I gathered the values are updating correctly even when I'm still declaring it from blueprint. It's probably because Client 2 is basically not owned by ThirdPersonCharacter_C_0 but ThirdPersonCharacter_C_1 so that's probably why I can't see it from the dedicated server. I probably wrong though.

[image]